# Use bash to write a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
echo "#!/bin/bash\nls -l /home/" > /home/myscript.sh
bash: !/bin/bash\nls: event not found
```

My script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l /home/
```

Why does it ignore the echo "" string and think that there is some sort of event? Why does it not recognize #!/bin/bash as a special word?

the same thing happens when I

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /home/myscript.sh
```

so it's not the new line!

```
echo -e "#\!/bin/bash" > /home/myscript.sh
```

writes the file content as:

```
#\!/bin/bash
```

Why is this simple action going miserably wrong?

Comment: `echo "\n"` does not write a newline, but a backslash and an `n`.  Perhaps try `printf` instead.

Comment: ```
printf "#!/bin/bash" > /home/myscript.sh
bash: !/bin/bash: event not found
```

Comment: Single quotes: `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nls -l /home/'`

Comment: yes mate! strange though, how would anyone guess that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nls -l /home/' > /home/myscript.sh`

a combination of `-e` and using single quote fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

From the bash manpage:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of
> all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $,  `,  \,
> and,  when  history  expansion  is
> enabled,  !.

So either use single quotes, or disable history expansion with `set +o history`.

But don't use `echo`.  Instead, do :

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'ls -l /home/' > /home/myscript
```

or

```
cat > /home/myscript << 'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
ls -l /home/
EOF
```

Comment: I get ` #!/bin/bash\nls -l /home` as the file contents from this